# Conversion of energy to mass with radioactive decay

Tags: homework-and-exercises, radioactivity, mass-energy

Consider the following problem:

*The nuclei of Am-241 decay by the emission of $\alpha$-particles with a kinetic speed of $8.8 \cdot 10^{-19} J$. In a certain source of Am-241 there are $ 4.0 \cdot 10^3$ decaying nuclei per second. Caculate the mass this source loses per year.*

So what the correction sheet tells me is that you basically just have to find the mass of an $\alpha$-particle in $kg$ and then just multiply that number until you get the amount of decaying $\alpha$-particles in a year.

However, I think this is wrong, since the $8.8 \cdot 10^{-19} J$ isn't accounted for. I'd say you have to take the mass of the $\alpha$-particle, then add to that the  $8.8 \cdot 10^{-19} J$ after you've converted it to $kg$ by using $E = mc^2$ and THEN multiplying that number in order to get the amount of decaying $\alpha$-particles in a year.

Which is correct, or perhaps better: which is less wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Work it out both ways and compare the difference in mass, you should get it being zero to all intents an purposes